# if $f_n' \to g $ in $C([0,1])$ why does $|\int f'_n\,d\mu - \int g \,d\mu| \leq \|f'_n - g \|_{\infty} \to 0$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence in $E \subset C^1([0,1])$ where $E$ is closed. Now define a new sequence of derivatives: $(Df_n)_n = (f'_n)_n$. Assume that $f'_n \to g$ in $C([0,1])$. Now the claim is:

Since $f'_n \to g$ in $C([0,1])$ we have that
$$
\left|\int_{0}^{t} f'_n \,d\mu - \int_{0}^{t} g \,d\mu \right| = \int_{0}^{t} |f'_n - g| \,d\mu \leq \|f'_n - g \|_{\infty} \to 0,
$$
where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I don't understand how the equality holds (maybe misprint) but I definitely don't understand the inequality between integral and norm.

Comment: The first equality is actually an inequality, due to the standard integral inequality $|\int f| \le \int |f|$.

Comment: Yeah, that I would like to argue also. But this is straight from the solution manual. @Crostul

Comment: The $\infty$-norm is defined as the max of $f'_n-g$, and because $f'_n$ are continuous in a compact space we have the uniform continuity, which by definition is $||f'_n-g||\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$

Comment: Its the supremum, and also it doesnt explain why $\int |f'_n - g| \leq \|f'_n - g \|$. @Giulio

Comment: Gonna write an answer

Comment: Nevermind, Matthew was faster

Comment: You want $f_n^\prime$, not $f_n$, in your title.

Comment: @Olba12: Keep in mind that the solution manual is not written by the textbook author, and it may not be reviewed with the same scrutiny.  So typos and errors are known to arise.  In one of my classes there is a solutions manual available online that contains the error $4^2 = 25$. It's easy to find who is really doing their homework when that occurs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Crostul points out, the inequality is $$ \left|\int f\,d\mu \right| \leq \int |f|\,d\mu$$
and it comes from the triangle inequality.  Indeed, suppose $f = \sum_{i=1}^n s_i \chi(E_i)$ is a simple function.  Then
$$
\left|\int f\,d\mu \right| = \left|\sum_{i=1}^n s_i \mu(E_i) \right| 
\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |s_i| \mu(E_i) = \int |f|\,d\mu
$$
The fact that it extends from simple functions to measurable functions is left as an exercise (or it's in your textbook).

For the second, note that if $h$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, then
$$
    \int_a^b h(x)\,dx \leq (b-a) \cdot \max_{a \leq x \leq b} h(x)
$$
So
$$
\int_0^t |f'_n -g| \,d\mu \leq t \cdot \max_{0 \leq x \leq t}  (f'_n-g)(x)
\leq 1 \cdot \max_{0 \leq x \leq 1} (f'_n-g)(x)  = \left\Vert f'_n - g\right\Vert_{\infty}
$$

Comment: Faster than me! Was just posting the same answer! Nice

Comment: You want $f_n^\prime$, not $f_n$, in your last line.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thank you for catching that typo.  Fixed.